# Targeting only the image CSS on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I currently have this code below:

```
<div class="categorytiletext">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr">
        <img class="imagetest img-responsive-100 newimgheight" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mobilewhite">
        <div class="testdiv">
            <h5 class="captext"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do, is when you hover over the surrounding div (Categorytiletext), ONLY the image will have the class 'hovereffect' added, which changes the opacity.

Using this script:

```
jQuery(".categorytiletext").hover(function(){
    jQuery('.categorytiletext').toggleClass('hovereffect');
});
```

This basically adds the class to the whole div (which it is coded to do), but I ONLY need the image to have the class.

Any ideas?

EDIT:::

I will have more than 1 of these, as it is in a loop. So is there a way to ONLY tagret the current image in the CURRENT div

Comment: No need to use jQuery or Javascript for this use case, see my answer below. Use CSS.

Comment: If you insist on using jQuery (even though it is absolutely not necessary here), make sure you use `jQuery(this)` inside your :hover-function rather than selecting **ALL** matching containers by doing `jQuery('.categorytiletext')` again.

Answer (score 5):

You do not even need to use Javascript or jQuery for this, this can be more easily done with css:

```
.categorytiletext:hover .imagetest { copy your .hovereffect styles here }
```

Working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXLBvv

Comment: Tried this, still no luck im afraid

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you copied from somewhere, anyways, add correct selector for the thing you want to toggle:

```
  jQuery(".categorytiletext").hover(function(){
        jQuery('.imagetest').toggleClass('hovereffect');
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I tried this, but the hovereffect doesnt work when I use this

Comment: Does this:   jQuery(".categorytiletext").hover(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery('.imagetest').toggleClass('hovereffect');
}); Work?

Comment: No, It only works when you hover over the actual image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class just to the image, then just target only the image. Its that simple. Your function's code will be:

```
jQuery('img.imgtest').toggleClass('hovereffect');
```

Maybe code is working, but your styling is not. Which may happen if other style rules are getting preference. If that is the case, then add **!important** after your style rule's value, such as:

```
.hovereffect {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: It needs to work when you hover over the div though?

Comment: Yes I get your point. I have just written your function's internal code. Make sure your style rules are getting preference as I mentioned

Comment: I tired this, even just to hide the image:

  .categorytiletext:hover .imagetest {     
    display: none !important;
  }

Comment: Please also add your related style rules in the question. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to target just the image bearing in mind that there's a context to consider, in case there are other images with the same selector:

```
jQuery(".categorytiletext").hover(function(){
    jQuery('.imagetest',this).toggleClass('hovereffect');
    //OR jQuery(this).find('.imagetest').toggleClass('hovereffect');
});
```

Comment: Again, this just makes the effect on the image appear when you hover over the actual image?

Comment: Can you create a minimal demo that we can trouble shoot.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better than you work with parent and get the child, so you should right something like this:

```
jQuery(".categorytiletext").on('hover', function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.find('img.imagetest').toggleClass('hovereffect');
});
```

Because maybe you have some more `img` with `imagetest` class !

Answer (score 0):

Ok here I have done some major editions and I hope it will work. Still, it is simple. Check 
[this out](http://jsfiddle.net/tac71sxu/1/) .

```
$('.container').mouseover(function () {
$('.image').toggleClass('hovereffect');
});
```

I have used *mouseover* instead of *hover*. I guess they are the same. I did not use a real image as Im on a mobile device, you know its not convinient.

**Edit:**

Ok now I have updated code as you have edited the question. But still you could do it yourself if there are more divs. [Here is the edited version.](http://jsfiddle.net/tac71sxu/3/)